# how is vector space different from the span of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Span is the linear combination of given <strike>linear independent</strike> vectors.
Vector space is set of linear independent vector and their combinations.

Seems like span should be a subset of vector space.
But for two vectors(i&j) the vector space is same as span of the vector.

[Advanced Engineering Mathematics Textbook by Erwin Kreyszig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGIzI.jpg) says they are same but then why we use different names.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Sure, if your spanning set contains a basis, then their span can equal the whole space.  Otherwise, the span will only be a subspace.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: A span is a subset of some ambient vector space. That doesn't stop them from being equal some times.

Comment: So the difference is that, the span is just the linear combination of independent vectors. And vector space is linear combination + basis vector.

Comment: @arthur, equal at times but not always. Maybe examples when they are not equal will be helpful

Comment: It is not true that "the span is just the linear combination of independent vectors".  The vectors in the spanning set may be independent but they do not have to be.

Answer (score 1):

The definitions you are using apparently conflict.  As far as I know, the span of a set of vectors (not necessarily independent) is the set of linear combinations of elements of the original set.

If the set of vectors $B_X$ is linearly independent, then it's a basis for some vector space $X$ and $\text{span}(B_X) = X$.

But if $B_X$ is not linearly independent, when $B_X = \{x_1 ... x_n\}$, then $\dim(\text{span}(B_X)) \leq n$.

Comment: What will be the vector space of $B_x$, when $B_x$ is linearly dependent?

Answer (score 0):

By definition span of a given set of vectors, not necessarly independent, is the set of vectors which are linear combination of the given set, therefore span is a subspace.

When the given set contains a basis for the vector space, the span coincides with the whole space.

Comment: What is the vector space of linear dependent vectors?

Comment: Any set of (not zero) vectors span a subspace and the set has a subset of linear independent vectors which span the same subspace. The number of vectors invthe basis is by definition the dimension of the subspace.

Comment: you are right. But this is not what i asked. I am asking what is the vector space of 2i and 4i vectors (clearly dependent). The span of 2i and 4i is the complete x axis.

Comment: The same concept applies, in this case the basis is one vector and the span is a line that is a subspace with dimension equal to $1$.

Comment: i see, so you mean vector space is like $ R^n$ always but span(or subspace) is defined for some finite vectors.

Comment: Span is always a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ with dimension equal to the maximum number of independent vectors among the ones which define the span.

Comment: What is vector space??

Comment: Refer to [that](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) for the definition.

Comment: A vector space is a set or a subset but a subset not always is a vector space.